# Java Add random letters to Character[]

Tags: java, character

i have this:

```
Character[] letters = new Character[30];
```

i want to add random letters to it and this is what i'm doing:

```
Character[] letters = new Character[30];

Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'A');
System.out.printf("\nI: " + i + "C: "+c);

letters[i] = c; 
};
```

Also:

```
letters.add('A'); //doesn't work error: cannot find symbol add
letters[0] = 'A'; //this works
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how do i fill Character[] letters = {}; with 30 random letters

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, he probably gets `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with current code

Comment: What do you mean by _fill_? You created an array of size 0.

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays are of a fixed length. To populate your array with 30 characters (based on your `for` loop), you could change `Character[] letters = {};` to something like

```
Character[] letters = new Character[30];
```

**or**

```
char[] letters = new char[30];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a one-liner?

```
Character[] letters = Stream.generate(Random::new)
    .limit(30)
    .map(r -> new Character((char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'A')))
    .toArray(new Character[30]);
```